How to wrap sync Sub in Async task?
I am developing a WinForms application (.Net 7), which consist of one starter form, from which with buttons the user can open a couple of different child forms, each showing charts with statistics retrieved from a MySQL database.
So far the application was synchronous, so any opened form was blocking the UI while the MySQL query was executed. I decided to make the app asynchronous, mainly to make it possible that the user is able to use the other forms (form2, form3, etc.) while a longer query is running in form1.
The thing is that the only asynchronous part of the class is the function that initiate the MySQL query and returning a datatable with the results of the query. The rest of the code is a Sub used to create the charts, which according to recommendations cannot be asynchronous.
My questions:

How should I wrap the Sync Sub, which modifies the winform in an Async Task? I tried some approaches, but with no luck due to exceptions. My attempts are listed below.
Since the Async Task is running on a different thread than UI, how should I make it possible that the task modifies the UI thread? I tried Invoke, but I cannot figure out how to implement it in my case when a loop is used (see below).
Is it worth doing that at all? My idea is when a query is triggered in Form1 and the user is on Form2 not to have blocks while UI in Form1 is being updated by the Sync Sub, which is wrapped in Async Task. As long as the query is running in Form1 there are no blocks in Form2, but when the charts' update process is reached there are short blocks in Form2 by the Sync Sub. That is what I would like to avoid making the Sub Async. Should I expect that this could happen provided that I manage to find a solution of the questions in points 1 and 2?

A simplified example of one WinForm class is shown below. There are comments describing in brief what the different lines are designed to do.
Public Class Form1

    Public Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim TabCell As New DataTable
        'TabCell is the statistical table used to build the charts

        Dim getStats As New Queries
        'Queries is a class with different functions for
        'extracting data from MySQL database

        TabCell = Await Task(Of DataTable).Run(Function() getStats.ExecQuery("some parameters"))
        'ExecQueryPar is a function of Queries class,
        'which returns a datatable with statistics.
        'This is done asynchronously, because query can
        'take quite a time

        Dim TabCharts As New DataTable
        'Each row of TabCharts contains the definition of one chart

        TabCharts = Await Task(Of DataTable).Run(Function() getStats.ExecQuery("select " +
                                    "ChartNo,Chart_KPI_Name,KPI from config_charts"))
        'Parameters for each chart definitions are retrieved from database.

        For i As Integer = 0 To TabCharts.Rows.Count - 1
            ChartDefs.ChartsDaily(Me.Controls.Find("Chart" + TabCharts.Rows(i)("ChartNo").ToString, True).FirstOrDefault(),
                                TabCell, TabCharts.Rows(i)("Chart_KPI_Name"), TabCharts.Rows(i)("KPI"))
        Next
        'ChartDefs is a class containing code for creation of charts.
        'ChartsDaily is a Sub for a specific type of chart.
        'The empty charts were created when loading the form, so they
        'already exist. In the loop each chart is fetched by its
        'object name and ChartsDaily sub is applying parameters
        'to each chart.s.

    End Sub

End Class

The class ChartDefs:
Public Class ChartDefs
    Public Shared Sub ChartsDaily(ch As Chart, Tab As DataTable,
                     title As String, serie1 As String)

        ch.DataSource = Tab

        'further code for filling the chart with data and
        'formating of series, axis, etc
    End Sub
End Class

What I tried so far to make the Sub to act asynchronously:

Attempt 1 It results in System.InvalidOperationException  'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Chart1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

For i As Integer = 0 To TabCharts.Rows.Count - 1
                    Await Task.Run(Sub() ChartDefs.ChartsDaily(Me.Controls.Find("Chart" + TabCharts.Rows(i)("ChartNo").ToString, True).FirstOrDefault(),
                             TabCell, TabCharts.Rows(i)("Chart_KPI_Name"), TabCharts.Rows(i)("KPI"))
                       End Sub)
Next


Attempt 2, resulting in two types of exceptions:

System.InvalidOperationException 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
and
System.InvalidOperationException  'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Chart1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
The code in which I transformed the Sub into Function, which returns a dummy value:
For i As Integer = 0 To TabCharts.Rows.Count - 1
     Dim ret As Integer = Await Task(Of Integer).Run(Function() ChartDefs.ChartsDaily(Me.Controls.Find("Chart" + TabCharts.Rows(i)("ChartNo").ToString, True).FirstOrDefault(),
                             TabCell, TabCharts.Rows(i)("Chart_KPI_Name"), TabCharts.Rows(i)("KPI")))
                       
Next

Public Shared Function ChartsDaily(ch As Chart, Tab As DataTable,
                 title As String, serie1 As String) As Integer

    Dim ret As Integer = 0
    ch.DataSource = Tab
    'further code for filling the chart with data and
    'formating of series, axis, etc

    Return ret
End Function

This question is a follow-up to this one

The old charting library doesn't provide asynchronous methods to initialize / fill the charts. You should probably move away from it, also considering that it's not exactly available in case you decide to update to .NET 6+. Try LiveCharts2 -- You should not be doing this: Dim TabCell As New DataTable '[...] TabCell = Await Task(Of DataTable).Run(...): you're creating a new DataTable object, to then just discard it and replace it with the return value of the Task. Just Dim TabCell = Await Task.Run(...) <- the return Type is inferred

@Jimi you are right about Await Task(Of DataTable).Run that it should not be done. For many years I have been using the .Net Framework charting object. But recently I have upgraded to .Net 7, so I switched to winforms-datavisualization. kirsan31 did a great job there, but I think there are no async charts. Your suggestion about LiveCharts2 is interesting, so I will take a look at it.

If you haven't already done so, I would recommend to read everything Stephen Cleary has written about async.

This answer originates from question's author. I managed to find a way to wrap a Sub in an Async Task, so that it modifies the UI from another thread. I think it is worth doing that, because the responsivness of UI is hugely improved. But in case that you are running a multiple async Winforms at the same time there might be some lag in the UI. But if the Winform is just one there are no lags (I can estimate that from the operation of a ProgressBar with a marquee style and also by clicking within the form).
The loop from the example in the question should look like following:
Dim s As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To TabKPImc.Rows.Count - 1
        s = i
        Await Task.Run(Sub()
                           Me.Invoke(Sub() Task.Run(Sub() ChartDefs.ChartsDaily(Me.Controls.Find("Chart" + TabCharts.Rows(i)("ChartNo").ToString, True).FirstOrDefault(),
                             TabCell, TabCharts.Rows(i)("Chart_KPI_Name"), TabCharts.Rows(i)("KPI")))
                        End Sub)
Next

Another example is below where there is no loop. In this example the Sub is modifying all charts in all tabs of a TabControl.
For i As Integer = TabControl1.TabPages.Count - 3 To 0 Step -1

    Dim chartCollection = From txt In TabControl1.TabPages(i).Controls.OfType(Of Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart)()
                            Order By txt.Location.Y, txt.Location.X

    For Each chartControl In chartCollection

        Dim chart As Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart = TryCast(ctrl, Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart)

        Await Task.Run(Sub()
                            Me.Invoke(Sub() SuppDailySubs.updBind(chart,
                            Tab, objectid, interval, days))
                        End Sub)
    Next

Next

